# Databricks: Uploading a file to another location from Azure Blob Storage without copying it locally

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I have a file in Azure Blob Storage, and I would like to upload it to another location without copying it to Databricks' local storage.

Currently my code needs to copy it locally before uploading:

```
# Set up connection to Azure Blob Storage
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.[some location]", "[account key]")

# Copies the file to Databricks local storage
dbutils.fs.cp("wasbs://[folder location]/some_file.csv", "temp_some_file.csv")

# Setting up for upload data to other system
uploader = client.create_dataset_from_upload('data', 'csv') # This is an external library call

# Read the local copy file and upload it to another system
with open('/dbfs/temp_some_file.csv') as dataset:
    uploader.upload_file(dataset)
```

How to change the `open()` command to point directly to the file in Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [mount the container in DBFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts):

```
storage = ...
container = ...
sas = '...'

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = f"wasbs://{container}@{storage}.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/uploader",
  extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.sas.{container}.{storage}.blob.core.windows.net": sas}
)
```

So it will be accessible at `dbfs:/mnt/uploader`. And, since DBFS itself is mounted on driver/executors at `/dbfs`, you will be able to directly open a file:

```
with open('/dbfs/mnt/uploader/some_file.csv', 'r') as dataset:
    uploader.upload_file(dataset)
```

Don't forget to unmount (unless you want that permanently).